# How can I safely handle this varargs function?

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I've written a method that makes it easy to set the path part of a URL using format strings.  Originally, I just passed the format string and args directly into `initWithFormat:`, but someone starting passing me args with spaces inside.  I changed the method to percent encode the arguments before going to `initWithFormat:`.

I might call it like `[request setUrlWithFormat:@"users/%@/timesheets", username]` where `username` could be `bmauter` or `b mauter`.

```
- (void) setUrlWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ... {

    // loop through varargs and cleanse them for the URL path
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSMutableArray *cleaned = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *s = format; s != nil; s = va_arg(args, NSString *)) {
        if (s == format) continue;
        [cleaned addObject:[s stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]]];
    }
    va_end(args);

    // put the cleansed values back into a varargs list
    __unsafe_unretained id  *argList = (__unsafe_unretained id *) calloc(1UL, sizeof(id) * cleaned.count);
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < cleaned.count; i++) argList[i] = cleaned[i];
    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format, *argList];
    free(argList);

    [self setUrl:result];
}
```

Sometimes I crash with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the first `for` loop line.  Sometimes I crash on the `initWithString:` line.  Most of the time it works perfectly.

**Update:** Thanks again @uliwitness.  In case anyone else wants to see what I ended up with, here goes:

```
- (void) setUrlWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ... {

    DLog(@"format=%@", format);

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    NSMutableString *result = [format mutableCopy];

    NSRange range = [result rangeOfString:@"%@"];
    while(range.location != NSNotFound) {

        NSObject *obj = va_arg(args, NSObject *);
        NSString *dirty = nil;
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) dirty = (NSString *)obj;
        else dirty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj];

        NSString *clean = [dirty stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
        DLog(@"dirty=%@, clean=%@", dirty, clean);

        [result replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:clean];

        range = [result rangeOfString:@"%@"];
    }
    va_end(args);

    DLog(@"result=%@", result);

    [self setUrl:result];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making several assumptions here that are simply not true. For one, you are not passing NIL in as a vararg, so you can't assume there will be a NIL. Instead, you have to count the number of format placeholders, and only grab that many varargs.

What you are doing right now is running off the end of the argument list. Sometimes you're lucky, and the random memory behind this list turns out to be 8 zero bytes, and so it looks like NIL and your loop terminates. When it crashes, you get some other random bytes that are not a valid object pointer, or look like a pointer to a different class of object, that's why you crash.

Also, why are you assuming that you can just pass the first item of an array into NSString's -stringWithFormat: ? Your code happens to work in this test case, but that's only because you only have one format placeholder.

-initWithFormat: takes a matching number of parameters to its format string. Not a different number (like you are passing now), and not an array (which you probably think you are passing, but since arrays in C are pointers to the first item, and C can't tell a pointer to one object from a pointer to an array, and doesn't know how long the array is, all you're actually passing is one item).

To make this work, what you'll have to do is write your own version of format string parsing. A quick-and-dirty version would be to use rangeOfString to find the `"%@"`s, and then append the part before that to the string, then the escaped corresponding argument, and once your loop ends, whatever is left in the string.

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  Shortly after I posted, I figured out that I should be counting the number of format specifiers.  Knowing that solves all crashing that I've found so far on the first `for` loop.  I'm still stuck on the second `for` loop crash.  That code is trying to package an `NSArray` up into a varargs list.  I found that code here on SO and tweaked it for my purposes.  Ideally `NSString` would have an `initWithFormat:argsInArray`: type of method.  I guess you're also right that until that happens I'll just have to replace the format specifiers on my own.